# Converting Element to HTMLElement in javascript / typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting, nodelist

So, I'm getting a list of elements that match a selector using querySelectorAll, which stores them in a NodeList.

I'm then scanning through the NodeList with a forEach loop, at which point the type of each individualItem is "Element".

However, I'm feeding these individualItems into a function "doThing()" that expects individualItem to be of type "HTMLElement" (I'm using typescript). I'm wondering if there is some built in js function for converting an "Element" type into an "HTMLElement" type, or, if not, what a function like that might looks like

```js
const h = document.querySelectorAll(someClassString);

h.forEach(individualItem => {
            individualItem.addEventListener(c.EVENT, () => doThing(individualItem));
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To type the output from querySelectorAll you can do it this way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll<HTMLTableElement>('.mytable')
```

Comment: Even though the question owner accepted my answer, I think this is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using TypeScript, why don't you cast it to another type? See it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

```
const h = document.querySelectorAll(someClassString);

h.forEach(individualItem => {
    individualItem.addEventListener(c.EVENT, () => doThing(individualItem as HTMLElement));
});
```

**EDIT 2023**

I don't know if I had a limited knowledge of Typescript when I wrote this or if this functionality wasn't available yet, but as Ron Jonk pointed out, the most elegant and reusable solution is

```js
const h = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(someClassString);

h.forEach(individualItem => {
    individualItem.addEventListener(c.EVENT, () => doThing(individualItem));
});
```